# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:safedkInstrumentationRelease

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-arctic-fox

I'm getting this error whenever I try to generate signed apk after enabling minifyEnabled true.
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:safedkInstrumentationRelease' (type 'InstrumentationTask').

- Type 'com.safedk.gradleplugin.tasks.InstrumentationTask' property '$9' specifies file 'C:\Users\Junaid\AndroidStudioProjects\SampleApp\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt' which doesn't exist.

How can I fix it. It doesn't appear if I do minifyEnabled to false. I'm using Android Studio ArcticFox and build:gradle:7.0.1

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: I'm faceing the same error with (property '$13'), Gradle Version 7.0.0, Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 1):

Check your proguard-rules.pro file.

If it contains

```
-dontwarn
```

try to disable it (by making it `#-dontwarn`). it solved my problem.

EDIT : This problem was fixed in AppLovin Quality Service release  4.3.7.

Comment: Fixed via AppLovin Quality Service.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade Android Gradle Plugin Version from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
```

To:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

Solved my Error.

Answer (score 0):

1-Open your project Structure and Use this Gradle Version (see pic 1)
[image: Open your project Structure and Use this Gradle Version (see pic 1)]

2-go to setting.gradl and remove those lines. and keep just
rootProject.name and includes
[image: go to setting.gradl and remove those lines. and keep just rootProject.name and includes]

3-Finally add all project repositories in build.gradl
[image: add all project repositories in build.gradl]

Comment: No need of downgrade gradle, actual problem in Applovin quality services.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from Root-Level build.gradle File

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' } //this line
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:+" //this line
    }
}
```

Remove from App-Level build.gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'applovin-quality-service'
applovin {
       apiKey "-8kGo5ZJJLrBOcvCvM420upyw56ZH8IS2GbSutq_pGTvRO8QXWERBsnvc7VMlXdnSykCye8aJoa5RpwuZqZ9ps"    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove from App-Level build.gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'applovin-quality-service'
applovin {
       apiKey "-8kGo5ZJJLrBOcvCvM420upyw56ZH8IS2GbSutq_pGTvRO8QXWERBsnvc7VMlXdnSykCye8aJoa5RpwuZqZ9ps"    
}
```